# How to reuse existing mongo connection with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my nodejs application I have connection created to mongodb using the MongoDB driver.

```
const client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect(connectionString)
```

This works fine. But now I am trying to reuse the same connection with Mongoose, using the `setClient()` function as mentioned in the docs:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-setClient

```
const conn = mongoose.createConnection().setClient(client);

conn.readyState; // is 1 which indicates CONNECTED
```

But when I try to run query using Mongoose models like:

```
const data = await MyModel.find()
```

I get a `buffering timed out after 10000ms` error

Is this the correct way of using a existing mongo connection?
Alternative approaches welcomed as well

Comment: Why not using the same `client` object you already have?

Comment: I have some part of the application that makes use of Mongoose models. And I don't want Mongoose to create a new connection

Comment: If it is already connected, it won't connect again, you can use the same client.